# SQL inner join returns only one row

Tags: sql, inner-join

i am trying to get some info with inner join, from two tables, as in between them there is another - connective table - that makes them a total of 3 tables actually :) 
The problem is that the query returns only one row, everytime the same one actually - any suggestions?

```
 SELECT sales.id, suppliers.name, sales.baseprice, sales.paydatesupl 
 FROM SALES 
  INNER JOIN serv_supl ON (serv_supl.id = sales.idss)
  INNER JOIN suppliers ON (suppliers.id = serv_supl.IDSUPL)
```

tables are 'SALES', a table 'SERV_SUPL' - that connects the services and suppliers /FK in sales is IDSS/, and 'SUPPLIERS'- where i want to get the name from /instead of showing just an ID/ - fk is the IDSUPL.

thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide some data, the result you get and the expected result

Comment: You are getting one row because your join conditions are satisfied only once. For more help from here, you have to provide your database/version, sample data and expected output. Also not sure but you might want to consider `left join` if you want everything to returned from `sales`.

Comment: Hi Utsav, the Left Join is returning the full data from 'sales' excepts the suppliers.name - that is comming from the 'suppliers' table - only returning the final field, the final row. all other data is there. I am using this in Apex Oracle sql data base. Expected output is the list with the id-s from 'sales', names of suppliers - from 'suppliers', and price and date from 'sales' as well.

Comment: I got it guys , i just played a bit more with the columns and FK PK things, and finaly get it right. Thank you for the suggestions, the left join wasnt going to work, only INNER JOIN :)